# Accessing variables inside the function, initialized using "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, scope

I have code like this:

```
  'use strict';
  var mainState = function (game) {
      this.backgroundGraphics;
      this.ballSprite;
      ....
```

How can I access `ballSprite` from the global scope? `mainState` is defined in global score (not under any other function or variables).

Comment: No you can't....

Comment: Why not? Is there anything I can do to make it accessible?

Comment: `mainState` is a function. Those variables don't exist until you call the function.

Comment: Create a global copy to store the data in `this.ballSprite`

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a local variable from the global scope.
You can do this thing:

```
var mainState = function (game) {
    this.backgroundGraphics;
    this.ballSprite;
}
//...
var m = new mainState('Game Name');
console.log(m.ballSprite);
```